# embedding ooyala video without flashvars not working in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, embed, video-embedding, ooyala

I am trying to embed a ooyala video on a web page using the emebed tag. By just giving the src it works fine in chrome and surprisingly in IE, but if fails in FF.

```
<embed src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=c3ajR4MjpyGe-djJaAxM6wa_SPQPijH7&amp;version=2" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
/>
```

for firefox I additionaly need to provide a flashvars property in the embed tag or else it gets stuck on 'loading'.

```
<embed src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=c3ajR4MjpyGe-djJaAxM6wa_SPQPijH7&amp;version=2" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="&amp;embedCode=c3ajR4MjpyGe-djJaAxM6wa_SPQPijH7&amp;videoPcode=FiYm06Tu_hQLSGqTeVTwSS1L4vV7" 
/>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/an8p5/1/) demonstrating the issue. Open it in ff and you will see the second video forever stuck on loading while both the video play fine in chrome and IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<iframe></iframe>`

```
<iframe  id="Iframe" width="640" height="360" src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=c3ajR4MjpyGe-djJaAxM6wa_SPQPijH7&amp;version=2" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

it supports all browser

Comment: ahh, but sadly, i am using a ckeditor plugin which generates the above embed code, i just pass the url and the flashvars parameters to it. Refer to this ticket for more info http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10758